# A Tale of Snake and Coffee

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story

I had the strangest dream last night:

> I am in field of red stones. I start walking around until a smell of
>   fresh coffee catches my attention. I follow it until I see a large
>   cave, and in its entrance there's a snake.  The snake speaks to me: "I
>   will let you enter only if you can tell me what note i'm
>   playing." He pulls out an harmonica from his bag and starts playing. I try to
>   remember the music lessons I took a while back where I had to identify
>   notes. I think it might be Db. Is that right? Yes! The snake says it's
>   correct and lets me in.  I walk inside and see a box with some hard
>   covering and a strange force is pulling me towards it. I open it and
>   and see there is just one piece of paper and it reads... "*COFFEE*"?!

I wake up in confusion - what had I just dreamed about?

I glance at my watch and see it's 7:30 am. I go to the kitchen to drink some coffee before I head to work. But the confusion is still there. I can't remember what is my job.

**What's my job?**

Comment: Are you playing minecraft?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I bet you're a

> software developer

because

> your little story refers to **Ruby** (red stones), **Python** (snake), **Java** (coffee), **C#** (Db), **shell** (hard cover on box) and **Javascript** (COFFEE *written on a piece of paper*).

However,

> the strange force pulling you to the box is a bit of a mystery; perhaps it's just there for atmosphere, or perhaps generalcrispy's suggestion in comments of "git pull" is correct...

Comment: Hard covered box = (rot13) pbzchgre?

Comment: Maybe. Or rot13(pbagnvare) or something, but it feels like there may be something more _specific_ going on here.

Comment: That's correct! One more to go

Comment: First guess on the box is right (1 of 2 parts)

Comment: Maybe it had a (rot13) tvg chyy.

Comment: Ugh. I suppose you could be right.

Comment: rot13(furyy) is right

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted you about that bit. My apologies.

Comment: I thought Db meant (rot13) Qngnonfr, but this makes more sense.

Comment: Nope! Not this time.

Comment: rot13(Gur pubvpr bs "pbssrr" ba cncre gb qrfpevor WninFpevcg vf xvaq bs shaal orpnhfr gurer'f npghnyyl n ynathntr pnyyrq PbssrrFpevcg.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Ah, didn't know that!

Comment: There is an explanation behind the "force" that goes together with the hard covering you already got (not yet discovered).